# If $S$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $S \circ S = S$, prove that $S$ can be:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, projection

We have that $S \circ S = S$, I want to prove that $S$ can be

1. $S = 0$ (The zero transformation) or
2. $S(x) = x$ (The Identity transformation) or
3. $S$ can have a basis $A$ such that $[S]_{A}^{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 && 0 \\
   0 && 0
   \end{pmatrix}$

I have that all of the three propositions are True, 3 is like to say that S can be a projection, in this case, over the $x$-axis, 2 can be done by see that $S(x) = S(S(x)) = x$, but what do you think? I try to find more about in the some books (I study for myself, not attending a school for now, but I love math, I try to solve the most, but some are really strange for me) thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 mutually exclusive and exhaustive cases. One is, kernel is of dimension 2 in which case you get the zero operator i.e. S=0, second case,  when kernel is of dimension zero in which case you get the identity operator i.e. S=I and third case,  kernel is of dimension one in which case image is of dimension one and you get the matrix you have given in your third case.

Answer (score 1):

If $\text{im}(S)$, the image of $S$, is $0$-dimensional then $S=0$.

If $\text{im}(S)$ is $2$-dimensional then any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as $S(x)$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, so the relation $S(S(x))=I(S(x))$ implies that $S=I$.

Consider the final case where $\text{im}(S)$ is $1$-dimensional. We claim there is a non-zero vector which $S$ fixes. Indeed, take an $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$. If $S(x)=x$ we are done. If not, then the relation $S\circ S=S$ implies that $S$ fixes $y=x-S(x)$. Now take any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is linearly independent of this $S$-fixed vector and you have the basis for the final case.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is such that $S^2 = S$ then

$$
S^2 - S = 0
$$

and so $S$ is annihilated by the polynomial $x^2 - x = x(x - 1)$. Therefore, the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) $\mu_S(x)$ of $S$ divides $x(x - 1)$. This leaves only three possibilities:

1. $\mu_S(x) = x$ which means that $S = 0$.
2. $\mu_S(x) = x - 1$ which means that $S = I$.
3. $\mu_S(x) = x(x - 1)$ which means that both $0$ and $1$ are the eigenvalues of $S$ and therefore we have

$$
S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

in the eigenbasis of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, this is really just a classification of the possible ranks of $S$ ("rank" here meaning the dimension of the image $S(\mathbb{R}^2)$, which can only equal $0,1$ or $2$). Here is a detailed argument that avoids using minimal polynomials:

If $S$ is rank $0$, then $S(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has dimension zero and is hence $\{0\}$, meaning $S$ is the $0$ transformation.

If $S$ is rank $2$, then it is invertible (it has trivial kernel by rank-nullity), so precomposing the equation $S^2 = S$ with $S^{-1}$ gives $S = I$, the identity.

Finally, suppose $S$ is rank $1$. The space $S(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so take a basis vector $u$ of this subspace. Also note $S(u)=u$ (which can be seen by writing $u=S(x)$ and using $S^2=S$). Since the kernel of $S$ also has dimension $1$, we can pick a basis vector $v$ of this subspace as well. We claim $\{u,v\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. By dimension it suffices to show $\{u,v\}$ is a linearly independent set. If $\lambda_1u+\lambda_2v=0$, then applying $S$ to this equation gives $\lambda_1u = 0$, so $\lambda_1=0$. But then $\lambda_2v = 0$, so $\lambda_2=0$ as well. This proves the claim.

Finally, put $A = \{u,v\}$. Since $S(u) = (1)u+(0)v$ and $S(v) = (0)u+(0)v$, it has the desired matrix representation
$$[S]_A^A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

As a final remark: the property $S^2=S$ is called idempotence, and this result generalizes to higher dimension. See, for example, this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958669/idempotent-linear-transformation-from-v-to-v-is-the-direct-sum-of-operator).